# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Ayuda por qué me sale ese error

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
    import math
    a = input("Ingrese a ")
    b = input("Ingrese a ")
    c = input("Ingrese a ")
    s = (a+b+c)/2
    if a+b >= c:
        raiz = math.sqrt(s(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
        print raiz
    else:
        print "El triángulo no es posible"
```

Comment: Hola Astaroth, sería ideal que agregaras algo más de información: ¿Qué es lo que hace este código? ¿En qué línea da el error? Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro no son de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar la entrada debe ser un entero (int) no una cadena (str), python por defecto maneja solo el 'input' como 'str' o cadena.
Ahora bien teniendo a la ecuación s=(a+b+c)/2 (debes tener en cuenta que esto es un float)

```
math.sqrt(s(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
```

Aqui debes recordar que todas las variables deben ser un numero ya sea float o int.

```
s(s-a)
```

Aqui es el error, porque como lo mencione todo es un entero, y aqui es como si lo manejaras como una función o clase, te marca que no es 'suscriptable' puesto que los enteros no se manejan de es forma, si lo que querias era que se multiplicara debias escribirlo asi.

```
s*(s-a)
```

Aquí te mando el código modificado.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import math
a = int(input("Ingrese a "))
b = int(input("Ingrese a "))
c = int(input("Ingrese a "))
s = (a+b+c)/2
print(s)
if a+b >= c:
    raiz = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    print (raiz)
else:
    print ("El triángulo no es posible")
```

Comment: Se le tiene que especificar el tipo de dato a s?

Comment: Para 'a' debes especificarlo como entero ya que solo input por defecto es entero, luego para 's' no porque se supone toda la ecuación es conformada por números enteros, pero si lo deseas como entero y no flotante puedes hacer división entera que seria (a+b+c)//2, o especificarlo como int()

Comment: Una pregunta, el if está bien, porque al probarlo y usar a 1 b 2 c 1 me da true, y es false

Comment: De hecho es True puesto que con a=1 , b=2 y c=1 tenemos que: 1+2>=1 y eso es True, si no quieres eso deberias cambiar el signo de mayor o igual por menor o igual.

Comment: No se supone que al ser un 3, un valor mayor que 1 debería ser false?

Comment: Recuerda que los condicionales se cumplen si es True. En este caso python pregunta, 3 es mayor o igual que 1?, y eso es verdad, por ende se cumple.

Comment: Tremenda confundida, creo que ya entendí, gracias

Answer (score 1):

reemplazar:

```
s(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
```

con:

```
s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
```

Comment: Está bien el if? porque al ser a y b menores que c, de igual manera ejecuta la raiz

Comment: Para completar un poco la respuesta, sería ideal que añadieses una descripción del cambio que has hecho y por qué soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 1):

La causa del error ya está más que clara, la falta del operador `*` en la fórmula de Herón en `s(s-a)...` cuando debería ser `s*(s-a)...`. Al hacer`s()` estás haciendo un intento de llamada, al ser `s` un entero obtienes el error comentado. No obstante **el código mostrado es para Python 2** y esto implica tener dos cosas más en cuenta:

- Nunca se debe usar `input` en Python 2 para entradas de usuario a la ligera. `input` evalúa todo código Python válido que se ingrese, lo que significa una puerta abierta de par en par para ataques de inyección de código. Tal vez en casos como este parezca no tener mucha importancia, pero no deja de ser una muy mala práctica. En su lugar, en Python 2.x se debe usar `raw_input` (que retorna una cadena similar a lo que hace `input` en Python 3) y hacer un casting explícito.
- El operador de división (`/`) funciona de forma muy diferente en Python 2 y en Python 3. En Python 3 retorna siempre el resultado de la división real (5/2 => 2.5). En Python 2 el retorno depende del tipo de los operandos, por ejemplo **5/2** da como resultado **2** (división entera) porque ambos operandos son enteros, mientras que **5/2.0** nos retorna **2.5**. 
  Si haces un casting a int de tus entradas e ingresas `a = 3, b= 3, c = 5` tendrías un problema ya que el semiperímetro será 5 y el área será 0.0, lo cual dista bastante de los 4.1457...

Por otro lado, según el teorema de la desigualdad triangular un triángulo es válido si la suma de dos lados cualquiera es siempre mayor al lado restante. Solo compruebas una de las tres posibilidades en el `if`, el triángulo `a = 3, b = 12, c = 3` cumple `a + b >= c` pero es un triángulo inválido.

Con todo ello, si quieres que se puedan ingresar valores decimales para las medidas de los lados puedes hacer:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import math

a = float(raw_input("Ingrese a: "))
b = float(raw_input("Ingrese b: "))
c = float(raw_input("Ingrese c: "))


if ((a + b) > c) and ((a + c) > b) and ((b + c) > a):
    s = (a + b + c) / 2
    raiz = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    print raiz
else:
    print "El triángulo no es posible"
```

Si solo quieres aceptar enteros entonces haz:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import math

a = int(raw_input("Ingrese a: "))
b = int(raw_input("Ingrese b: "))
c = int(raw_input("Ingrese c: "))


if ((a + b) > c) and ((a + c) > b) and ((b + c) > a):
    s = (a + b + c) / 2.0  # Observa el 2.0 en vez de 2
    raiz = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    print raiz
else:
    print "El triángulo no es posible"
```

Answer (score 0):

te esta haciendo falta identificar el valor de entrada como entero, prueba del modo siguiente:

```
import math
a = int(input("Ingrese a "))
b = int(input("Ingrese a "))
c = int(input("Ingrese a "))
s = (a+b+c)/2
if a+b >= c:
    raiz = math.sqrt(s(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    print raiz
else:
    print "El triángulo no es posible"
```

Para que de este modo le indiques el tipo de dato a Python que va a ingresar